# Camera space normal misunderstanding

Tags: node-editor, camera, transforms, normals

I am trying to create a shader which uses camera space normals. To get those normals, I am using the `Geometry` node and the `VectorTransform` node as in the following graph.

[image]

The result of that graph use on a sphere looks like
[image]

If the camera looks towards along -Z axis, that means that all visible (front facing) points should be bluish, like in this other image created directly with OpenGL.

[image]

I guess I am misunderstanding something. Can someone guide me on what I am doing wrong/misunderstandnig?

Comment: Just set blue to 1. (Im not on Blender irght now, but I think the Z coordinates are negative in front of the camera.

Comment: Z is negative in front of the camera, but I am computing the normals. Normals point towards the camera, so Z should be positive

Comment: I didnt answer exactly to my question, but give me some clues. Multiplying Z component by -1 gave me the exact same values as in raw opengl. Not sure why is that...

Comment: Multiplying with (0, 0, -1) is not enough, since you'd just invert the Z component. You will have to multiply and shift to get the correct range for X, Y and Z.

Comment: @cegaton you are using the normal, but using the Vector Transform node for points. Is that correct?

Comment: @cegaton sorry, but could you explain your posts? How is the view vector (a vector from the camera to the shading point) similar to the normal vector in camera space?